# After moving my home folder to different drive, Photos behavior broken

Tags: macos, photos, mojave

I successfully moved my home folder to a different drive. All the special folders (Music, Pictures, Movies, etc.) have the correct icons. iTunes opens up and so does Photos. Etc. Life is good...almost.

But here's where things have gone south with Photos. Nothing catastrophic but certainly annoying. I believe the various incorrect behaviors I'm seeing with Photos are related.

1. New pics on my iPhone that used to sync automatically with Photos (via iCloud) no longer happen automatically. I can plug my iPhone in and import them into Photos, but this is annoying.
2. When I get the Finder window to choose a photo (say to upload to Reddit), I see Photos in the left panel, I can click it, and I see Photos library trying to populate, but it doesn't.

[image: In file chooser dialog, Photos doesn't populate]

3. Another thing that isn't working is the Share menu option "Add to Photos". I can open something up in Preview, hit the share icon, and choose "Add to Photos" and it appears to succeed, but nothing shows up in my Photos library.

It really does sound like the system doesn't really know where my Photos library is even though it's a subdirectory of my new (but correctly configured) home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the system photo library path is configured correctly. Open Photos with the photo library, then choose Photos → Preferences, double-check the path displayed for the photo library is correct and press **Use as System Photo Library**.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero! That fixed all my problems!